# Why is bash listing the effective content of /etc/hosts if I press Super_L+Space?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, hosts

The title pretty much sums it up.
I have some (minimal) content in `/etc/hosts`.

The file looks something like:

```
# some comment
127.0.0.1  localhost foo bar
1.2.3.4    baz
::1        localhost ip6-loopback ip6-localhost
```

I accidentally pressed Super_L+Space today when typing in bash, which immediately presented me something formatted like the output of `ls`, but listing all the functional content (not the comments) of that file *except* ip4-addresses, like that:

```
me@host$
::1   localhost      foo             bar
baz   ip6-loopback   ip6-localhost
me@host$ s
```

That `s` on the last prompt is not a typo by the way: The next prompt after the hosts listing looks exactly like that.

I can easily reproduce the behavior.

So far, I have looked into the keyboard shortcuts of KDE Plasma and the terminal emulators, but there is no action bound to Super_L+Space.
My `.bashrc` contains nothing related either.
If I press the combination in any other window but a terminal emulator, nothing happens.

The bash history does not even contain an entry about the event.

What is happening here?

Comment: Do you really have Meta key on your keyboard on do you meant Alt?

Comment: I mean the "Windows key". I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: Is there something interesting in output of `bind -p`?

Comment: Actually, yes... I did not know `bind` until now, so I'm still trying to figure out what the output is telling me, but there is something about "possibe-hostname-completions", which looks promising.

Comment: Interesting, can you post the entire line?

Comment: Sure. I just searched the output for "host", this is what i found:
```
"\e@": complete-hostname
"\C-x@": possible-hostname-completions
```

Comment: Well I don't think that's, I also have these keybindings but nothing happens when I press Super_L Space

Comment: To make sure this is Bash related issue and not window manager or terminal emulator's quirk switch to TTY (Control-Alt-F2), log in and press the keybinding. Does it still print contents of /etc/hosts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120243/discussion-between-turysaz-and-arkadiusz-drabczyk).

Comment: What the heck is Super_L?

Comment: It's the name of the key shown by `xev`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Konsole-specific feature introduced in commit [5ba34471](https://invent.kde.org/utilities/konsole/commit/5ba344714b8da55dfcc84823abac6f059a288386)
back in 2012.

Reference: this [Super User
question](https://superuser.com/questions/1238236/super-key-combinations-cause-weird-input-in-konsole)

---

A short summary of the mechanism as originally described in the linked Super User question is as follows:
`Super_L`+`letter` in Konsole sends `^X@s<letter>`.
The first part is "translated" into "possible-hostname-completions" by readline key bindings.
(`bind -p` shows `"\C-x@": possible-hostname-completions`). The remaining part (`"s<letter>"`) will be printed on the next prompt.